# Unable to fetch 20 NewsGroups dataset in Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, dataset, scikit-learn

I trying to fetch this datasets using the codes below.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
twenty_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train')
```

However, an error had occurred after this. The program is then killed.

```
No handlers could be found for logger "sklearn.datasets.twenty_newsgroups"
Killed
```

I try to load those files manually like this later

```
twenty_train = load_files('/root/scikit_learn_data/20news_home/20news-bydate-train')
```

and this

```
twenty_train = load_files('/root/scikit_learn_data/20news_home/20news-bydate-train',encoding='latin1')
```

Only the former one works.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like that scikit-learn is trying to report some error and you have not configured, where your output goes. Even I had the exact same problem when I tried your code. I fixed it by setting up my logger:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
```

Now trying to load the dataset gives me the following warning:

```
WARNING:sklearn.datasets.twenty_newsgroups:Download was incomplete, downloading again.
WARNING:sklearn.datasets.twenty_newsgroups:Downloading dataset from http://people.csail.mit.edu/jrennie/20Newsgroups/20news-bydate.tar.gz (14 MB)
```

After the download(14 MB) is completed on your system, you will have the dataset loaded in your `twenty_train` variable.

Hope this helps!